# iPod 160GB high realloc count

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, disk-utility, ipod

I recently acquired the iPod in question, model MC297 (Classic, Late 2008/7th Gen). The SMART diagnostics came as follows=
Retracts=7
Reallocs=16376
Pending sectors=0
Power on hours=163
Temp=current 31c
Temp min=9c
Temp max=53c.

From the research I've done, the 16k+ allocs might mean death is near. But it has worked fine for the 4/5 days I've had it. (the previous owner sold it to me cheap saying that it froze and played songs erratically, and I restored it to Apple format - it was in Windows).
What I want to know, since I've found conflicting opinions about this, is if I can erase the drive with Disk Utility (which I assume would push the bad blocks to one corner, so to speak) and then restore with iTunes.
And if this is not recommended, what would be the best course of action.
Thanks,

Comment: I always thought restoring would re-format, re-allocate. It's always fixed dodgy issues on my old spinning disk iPod; but I'm by no means certain

Comment: Me too, Tetsujin but I believe DiskUtility goes quite deeper. I ask before diving into it because there might be a risk of not being able to reinstall the OS thus rendering it useless

Comment: I've never resorted to that, so I really don't know, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin, as for the allocs count, would you say the drive is nearly dead, or does it stand a chance ? Anything I could do besides restoring ?

Comment: I had a look at mine for comparison. It's an '06 not sure what model. Retracts 17; Reallocs 0; Pending 0; Power on hours 129; Start/Stops 27296. Mine has periodically done 'weird' things & I've restored it from iTunes each time... it's still alive. Best I can say is keep using it til it fails. I really don't know what Disk Util may do that's different, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that was my plan unless someone gave me a tip about what to do.